# Selecting data based on number of occurences using Python / Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

My dataset is based on the results of Food Inspections in the City of Chicago.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:/~/Food_Inspections.csv")

df.head()
Out[1]: 
   Inspection ID                        DBA Name  \
0         1609238  JR'SJAMAICAN TROPICAL CAFE,INC   
1         1609245                     BURGER KING   
2         1609237   DUNKIN DONUTS / BASKIN ROBINS   
3         1609258          CHIPOTLE MEXICAN GRILL   
4         1609244      ATARDECER ACAPULQUENO INC.   

                        AKA Name  License # Facility Type             Risk  \
0                            NaN  2442496.0    Restaurant    Risk 1 (High)   
1                    BURGER KING  2411124.0    Restaurant  Risk 2 (Medium)   
2  DUNKIN DONUTS / BASKIN ROBINS  1717126.0    Restaurant  Risk 2 (Medium)   
3         CHIPOTLE MEXICAN GRILL  1335044.0    Restaurant    Risk 1 (High)   
4     ATARDECER ACAPULQUENO INC.  1910118.0    Restaurant    Risk 1 (High)
```

Here is how often each of the facilities appear in the dataset:

```
df['Facility Type'].value_counts()
Out[3]: 
Restaurant                          14304
Grocery Store                        2647
School                               1155
Daycare (2 - 6 Years)                 367
Bakery                                316
Children's Services Facility          262
Daycare Above and Under 2 Years       248
Long Term Care                        169
Daycare Combo 1586                    142
Catering                              123
Liquor                                 78
Hospital                               68
Mobile Food Preparer                   67
Golden Diner                           65
Mobile Food Dispenser                  51
Special Event                          25
Shared Kitchen User (Long Term)        22
Daycare (Under 2 Years)                18
```

I am trying to create a new set of data containing those rows where its Facility Type has over 50 occurrences in the dataset. How would I approach this?

Please note the list of facility counts is MUCH LARGER as I have cut out most of the information as it did not contribute to the question at hand (so simply removing occurrences of "Special Event", " Shared Kitchen User", and "Daycare" is not what I'm looking for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC then you want to [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
df.groupby('Facility Type').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 50)
```

Example:

```
In [9]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'type':list('aabcddddee'), 'value':np.random.randn(10)})
df

Out[9]:
  type     value
0    a -0.160041
1    a -0.042310
2    b  0.530609
3    c  1.238046
4    d -0.754779
5    d -0.197309
6    d  1.704829
7    d -0.706467
8    e -1.039818
9    e  0.511638

In [10]:
df.groupby('type').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)

Out[10]:
  type     value
0    a -0.160041
1    a -0.042310
4    d -0.754779
5    d -0.197309
6    d  1.704829
7    d -0.706467
8    e -1.039818
9    e  0.511638
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but should work.

```
FT=df['Facility Type'].value_counts()
df[df['Facility Type'].isin(FT.index[FT>50])]
```